# Can multiple small graphic card memory collect more mining hash rate

Tags: mining-pools, ethereum

If I set multiple 3GB GTX 1060 , It can generate more hash rate than single GTX 1070 6GB.
Can I still mining ETH by this 3 Gb cards when the bloCk size of eth is over 3 Gb.
EXPLAIN ME.

Answer (score -1):

Currently you can not do that.
DAG should be loaded to card's memory to mine. Current miner software do not support this kind of cross-card memory management